# How to disambiguate overloaded functions

Tags: swift, overloading

This is a totally contrived example I wrote while learning about function overloading in Swift. The following functions differ only in return type (the first function implicitly returns `Void` / `()` while the other returns `Int`).

```
func foo(x:Int, y:Int) {
}

func foo(x:Int, y:Int) -> Int {
  return 0
}

// Call the version which returns Int
let i: Int = foo(6, y: 7)

// Call the version which returns Void
let v: Void = foo(6, y: 7)

// Ambiguous
foo(6, y:7)  // How can I force a call to the Void version without using let/var?

// I thought this might work but doesn't
foo(6,y: 7) as (Int, Int) -> Void
```

Is there a way I can call the `Void` version without using `let`, i.e. some type of cast? **Again, I realize this is a contrived example but I'd like to understand the options here.**

Comment: I'm curious to know the answer, but as far as actually doing this ... don't. It's not very readable code, and then perhaps things might explode if one function signature is changed/removed and all of a sudden the old call sites to that function call the `Int` one instead. Here be dragons.

Comment: Thank you for your response @AMomchilov but as I said, I am just trying to understand how this works syntactically... I wouldn't use it in production code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disambiguate the two `foo` functions by casting the result:

```
foo(6, y: 7) as Int

foo(6, y: 7) as Void
```

or you can cast `foo` itself:

```
(foo as (Int, y: Int) -> Int)(6, y: 7)

(foo as (Int, y: Int) -> Void)(6, y: 7)
```

Note:  `()` may be used in place of `Void` in both instances.